# CodeTypeReference.ArrayRank alternative

Tags: .net, codedom

I'm using CodeDom to build smart classes from an XSD file.
To do that I create I do the following

```
            XmlSchemaImporter schemaImporter = new XmlSchemaImporter(xsds);
                CodeNamespace codeNamespace = new CodeNamespace(settings.Nmspace);

                // export the code inside the namespace
                XmlCodeExporter codeExporter = new XmlCodeExporter(codeNamespace, null, CodeGenerationOptions.GenerateProperties);

                // load objects fromm the XSD
                var maps = new List<XmlTypeMapping>();
                foreach (XmlSchema schema in xsds)
                {
                    if (settings.UseTypes)
                    {
                        foreach (XmlSchemaType schemaT in schema.SchemaTypes.Values)
                            maps.Add(schemaImporter.ImportSchemaType(schemaT.QualifiedName));
                    }
                    if (settings.UseElements)
                    {
                        foreach (XmlSchemaElement schemaT in schema.Elements.Values)
                            maps.Add(schemaImporter.ImportTypeMapping(schemaT.QualifiedName));
                    }
                    //if (settings.UseNotations)
                    //  {
                    //  foreach (XmlSchemaNotation schemaT in schema.Notations.Values)
                    //      maps.Add(schemaImporter.ImportTypeMapping(schemaT.QualifiedName));
                    //  }
                }
                // export all selected objects to the namespace code
                foreach (var map in maps)
                    codeExporter.ExportTypeMapping(map);

                // process the files to update classes and other objects
                CodeNamespace newCodeNamespace = PostProcess(settings, codeNamespace);
```

Inside the XSD are some multidimensions arrays (giving something like "byte[][] myarray;" inside the produced code).

When I parse all members found inside the XSD and the parser reaches one of these multidimensions arrays the CodeMemberField or CodeMemberProperty contains a Type property which contains an ArrayRank property supposed to indicate the number of dimensions of the array (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.codedom.codetypereference.arrayrank?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

However property.Type.ArrayRank is ALWAYS set to 1, whatever the number of dimensions.
When I debug the app I can see another property inside the Type one (which is a CodeTypeReference) called NestedArrayDepth which indicates 2 (the right number of dimensions) while ArrayRank remains set to 1, as you can see here
[image]

I don't know whether this is a bug in the framework or intentional.

My question would then be: **how do I get the real number of dimensions using CodeDom ? Is there a trick I don't know or do not suspect somewhere ?**

Comment: You're missing the difference between jagged and multi-dimensional arrays. You have an array of rank 1, containing arrays of rank 1. Not an array of rank 2, which would be `[,]`

Comment: Ok, interesting indeed, however for me the problem remains the same as in fact what I want to do is provider an initialiser like "byte[][] myarray=new byte[0][0];" Based on the ArrayRank or other information I can only create "byte[][] myarray=new byte[0];" because I don't know how to identify the fact there are multiple arrays at stake... You're just right and my question was improperly stated but I'm still stuck here. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally couldn't find a way to that.
It was in fact a jagged array and despite the fact CodeDom seems to identify it I don't know how to get the information.

I solved my issue by replacing the byte[][] types bu objects[] types and will take care of what I'm doing when accessing these data until I find another way to do.

So sad...